# Using CheckBox in Cell to Mute Beep Sound upon Value > 999

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function to make a beep sound whenever cell value crosses above 1999, also have a "Counter" cell to count the number of times values have been > than 1999. Function is working as expected, however now I need to embed a CheckBox, if checkBox is selected, the sound should be muted but the Counter should continue counting and when CheckBox is not checked it should continue to make Beep Sound. Here is my code. I m calling this function from the cell.

```
Function TargetCounter2KAC(RngMeasure As Range)        
    If RngMeasure.Value > 1999 Then
        If BlnAboveHundred2K = False Then
            IntCounter2K = IntCounter2K + 1
            Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Alert4Target2Filled.wav", _
              0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            
            BlnAboveHundred2K = True
        Else
            BlnAboveHundred2K = True            
        End If
    Else
        BlnAboveHundred2K = False
    End If

    TargetCounter2KAC = IntCounter2K
End Function
```

Comment: Do you want a real checkbox or just an X in a empty cell of the sheet?

Comment: This is not a Form, I am using regular excel sheet

Comment: I know.. But do you want the real checkbox or a cell value?

Comment: @Andreas A Real Checkbox, btw whats an X in empty Cell, I added a checkbox from the developer tabs in the sheet

Comment: That is when you click on an empty cell on a sheet and press the button on the keyboard marked with "X"

Comment: @Andreas if you are saying that an X typed in an empty cell will work as good as a check box, that will also work for me, but it should not stop the counter cell.

Comment: That should work for me, however i checkbox will look more neat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Active-X checkbox on your sheet:

[image]

You can use the properties to change the name if you want.

In your code change it to:

```
Function TargetCounter2KAC(RngMeasure As Range)
    
    If RngMeasure.Value > 1999 Then
        If BlnAboveHundred2K = False Then
            IntCounter2K = IntCounter2K + 1

            ' here is the change:
            if Sheets("Sheet1").checkbox1.Value = false then Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Alert4Target2Filled.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)

            ' or if you want a X in an empty cell method:
            'if Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "" then Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Alert4Target2Filled.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            ' if A1 is the cell to toggle on/off


            BlnAboveHundred2K = True
            
            Else
            
            BlnAboveHundred2K = True
                        
        End If
        
    Else
    
        BlnAboveHundred2K = False
        
    End If

    TargetCounter2KAC = IntCounter2K
    
End Function
```

Comment: let me check and i'll revert with the feedback

Comment: There is one less END IF Here, where would u put that?

Comment: `if Sheets("Sheet1").checkbox1.Value = false then Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Alert4Target2Filled.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)` is a inline if that does not require an `end if`.

Comment: @MohammadHaneefAhmad As Vincent says. You don' need `end if` if you put the if and command at the same line.

Comment: i have split the lines right after THEN so as to see the entire code without scrolling so if i have to out it where shall i do it. right after THEN

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. But why do you need to see the full line there? You see if checkbox value is false call playsound. Do you need to see more than that? Generally I never split lines, but that is a preference. The longer the line is the less inclined I am to split it, as long as I can see the start of the line what it does then I'm fine with that, or I add a comment above. That way It's cleaner

Comment: This has worked very nicely, However just quick question, If i would like to include a Command Button to enable and disable the beep , how would the code change

Comment: I added an End If and it was all sorted, thanks much for your help,let me know if i can replace the checkbox with a command button, how would you replace the code for it?

Comment: First of all, you can accept the answer. Adding a button instead is doable but it will be little more complex depending on what method you want done. You can link a button to a cell on the sheet, that way the cell has the "value" of the button. That is the easy way but it requires a helper cell.

Comment: Yes it is working fine for me, I have been able to add a command button and its working as expected, please tell me where can i accept the answer as Good, i am new to this

Comment: To the left of my answer there is controls. One of them should be a tick mark (just as in a checkbox), this makes the answer accepted and others can see that there is a correct answer to this question in the future